# How we can stream a CSV file using Java NIO Api?

Tags: java, nio

I am trying to stream a Big CSV file using java NIO, I am able to read the Data from CSV file. Please suggest any example how we can stream a CSV file. What code we need to append/changes in this below code.

Please see below code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
 
public class ReadFileWithFixedSizeBuffer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("airQuality.csv", "r");
 
        FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
 
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        while(inChannel.read(buffer) > 0)
        {
            buffer.flip();
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++)
            {
                System.out.print((char) buffer.get());
            }
            buffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.
        }
 
        inChannel.close();
        aFile.close();
    }
}
```

Any Help would be appreciate.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much point using [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) on files which are line by line format like [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Calling NIO [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines(java.nio.file.Path)) will simplify your logic, and [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) cleans up your file handling neatly:

```
Path file = Path.of("airQuality.csv");

try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file))
{
    lines.forEach(line -> {
        // Do something with each line here instead of:
        System.out.println(line);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello @DuncG, I have one doubt. Can we achieve CSV file streaming using above code ??

Comment: The above is just a cleaner starting point that does the same as your code example - SO is not a code writing service. If you want to parse the CSV to extract data to another data structure have a look at libraries such as Apache CSV https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: Yeah Thanks, Got it but my requirement is different. First I have to create one endpoint which can stream a CSV file from one location and send the response back using Java NIO in spring boot application. Till my exploration I haven't find any example and sample code related to same. So first thing Is it possible to stream a CSV file using java NIO if yes so how we can achieve it ??